# Will Power BI connects with Azure LUIS to Visualize the INTENTS?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-language-understanding

I would like to visualize LUIS INTETNS and UTTERANCE count to Power BI dashboard/report. Is there any azure connector available for power bi to connect with Azure LUIS and fetch the data ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Cognitive Services can be used as any other web API (see [Web.Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents) and [Tutorial: Integrate Power BI with the Text Analytics Cognitive Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/tutorials/tutorial-power-bi-key-phrases)), but if you have Power BI Premium (P1 or higher, A2 or higher, or EM2 or higher) there is some support already built in. You can add columns with data generated by Text Analytics, Vision or Azure Machine Learning models directly from Add column tab in the ribbon:

[image]

(see [Use AI Insights in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-ai-insights))

or in Dataflows:

[image]

(see [Tutorial: Use Cognitive Services in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-tutorial-use-cognitive-services))

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we have only pro license in PowerBI is it possible to connect powerBI to LUIS service and fetch the Applications and INTETNTS ? if not with pro license is there any other way to do it suggestion would be really helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Premium license is required only for the built in support. You are free to call any API you want, including Azure Cognitive Services APIs, directly. Take a look again on the second link from my answer.